# Any way to call a constructor (or any function/method) from data types without going through two templated functions?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

```
constructor_caller<int,int,char*>(boxed_data);

template<typename ... CONSTRUCTOR_PARAMETER_TYPES>
static void constructor_caller(BoxedDataType & args) {

    T * new_cpp_object = call_constructor_helper<CONSTRUCTOR_PARAMETER_TYPES...>(args, 
        std::index_sequence_for<CONSTRUCTOR_PARAMETER_TYPES...>());

}

template <typename ...Fs, size_t...ns> 
static T * call_constructor_helper(BoxedDataType & args, std::index_sequence<ns...>){
    // args contains the boxed parameters and CastToNative unboxes
    //   the value to a native c++ type
    return new T(CastToNative<Fs>()(args[ns])...);
}
```

I have another solution that involves recursive inheritance based on HEAD, TAIL... of the parameter types, but that's even longer than this example.

Also, I think to generalize this to work for normal functions, object methods, and constructors I'd need 3 different versions of this.   Is that correct?

Comment: For a given type `T`, you call a constructor like this: `T()` or `T( args )`, or with C++11 braces notation, `T{}` or `T{args}`. That creates a new object. You can also call a constructor by declaring a variable of the type.

Comment: You need to both provide a complete (but minimal) example, and a more clear explanation of what the question is about. Voted to close as lacking (relevant) example.

Comment: Hrm, I think the question is pretty clear.   It's all right there and works except for the BoxedDataType and the CastToNative, but the actual types aren't that interesting as it just has to work like it does in the code I put in the question.  I'm just looking for a way to not require that second call that creates the parameter pack for the index_sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing to much stuff at once.

Pass types as values:

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{constexpr tag_t(){}; using type=T;};
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag={};
template<class Tag>using type=typename Tag::type;
```

Pass constexpr values as types:

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t=std::integral_constant<std::size_t,I>;
template<std::size_t I>
constexpr index_t<I> index={};
```

Get nth arg:

```
const auto get_nth_from=[](auto&& src){
  return [&src](auto index, auto tag)mutable->decltype(auto){
    using F=type<decltype(tag)>;
    return CastToNative<F>()(src[index]);
  };
};

template<class T>
const auto construct=[](auto&&...args)->T*{
  return new T(decltype(args)(args)...);
};
```

Now write your code operating on a generic function object target.

```
namespace details {
  template<class...Ts, std::size_t...Is, class F, class Get>
  decltype(auto) call(std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& f, Get&& get) {
    return std::forward<F>(f)(get(index<Is>, tag<Ts>)...);
  }
}
template<class...Ts, class F, class Get>
decltype(auto) call(F&& f, Get&& get) {
  return details::call<Ts...>( std::index_sequence_for<Ts>{}, std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Get>(get) );
}
```

After all that work, `call_constructor` looks like this:

```
template<class T, class...Ts>
T* call_constructor(BoxedDataType & args){
  return call<Ts...>( construct<T>, get_nth_from(args) );
}
```

or somesuch.

One target passed to `call` constructs a `T`, another invokes a method, another a free function.

One thing turns a list of types to indexes+types then invoke a function becomes one operation.  Turning indexes+types into args another thing.  Turning ctor into a callable another thing.  Each does one thing, and does it well.

More bulk for one operation, but less code duplication, and new operations are easy.

The above uses C++14 for brevity, and lambdas as a matter of style.

Code not compiled (written on phone), so certainly contains typos.

Comment: @xaxxon Rough implementation added.